# Can you use HTML to upload a text input as a file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to take a user's input from a HTML text form

```
<input type="text" name="comments" value="Comment">
```

is there a way to submit that input text as a txt file when the user clicks on the submit button for the form like if I had a

```
type='file'
```

type of form?

(I can use native html, js, or php in this project)

Comment: start by reading the manual for [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). neither html or js allow you to write a file to the server, so it has to be php.

Comment: yeah, inputs are input and the only diff is slightly different back-end handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, make a directory with name `temp`, then put `.htaccess` file in it, which contains: `deny from all`.
Then make a php-script with code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    file_put_contents('temp/file.txt', $_POST['comments']);
}
```

don't forget about write permission for temp folder!

BUT! Never save files with `.php` extention, coz some true-hackers can write a php code in textarea and then save, and execute it (if you don't create `.htaccess` with `deny from all`). Also, you can deny executing of all files in your `temp/` directory using chmod (only for linux, for windows `.htaccess` will help you). Also you can put your `temp/` directory under the `www/` (webroot) directory of your server (the path to you `www/` directory is something like this: `/site.com/www/`, just make a dir with path: `/site.com/temp/`), then nobody will can to execute created files. Writing a file to this folder will be like this:

```
file_put_contents('../temp/file.txt', $_POST['comments']);
```

Comment: If you don't want the files to be publicly accessible, it's easier to store them outside of the web-root.

Answer (score 1):

If you want user's input as a text file rather than submitted text then you can use the following javascript method:

```
// JavaScript
function download(filename, text) {
    var dom = document.createElement('a');
    dom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    dom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    dom.click();
}
```

Catch the click event from button and then call download() function with filename and text from comments.

Answer (score 0):

The type="file" is to post a file threw a form. If you want to insert the text given by the user, you must handle that on your side. There is a couple of ways to insert content in a file, you can look at fwrite or file_put_contents.

Comment: This is not quite flag-worthy for not being an answer, but it's almost exactly the same as @Dagon's comment above... consider expanding your answer a bit please